# SharePoint 2013 - JavaScript - List Data fetch failed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model

I'm using the following to read data from a custom list in SharePoint 2013:

```
var items;


$(document).ready(function () { ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CustomAction, "sp.js"); });

function CustomAction() {

    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ChapterTeeContest');
    var camlQuery = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
    items = list.getItems(camlQuery, 'Total Events');
    context.load(items,'Include(Title,Total Events)');
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onListDataSucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onListDataFailed)); 

    function onListDataSucceeded(sender, args) {
        var listItemEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        console.log(oListItem.get_item('Title') + oListItem.get_item('Total Events'));
        }
    }

    function onListDataFailed(sender, args) {
        console.log('List Data fetch failed. ' + args.get_message() + 'n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }

}
```

and I have a custom list with 3 columns:

```
Title, Event Label, Total Events
```

But for some reason when I run this script I get the following message...

```
List Data fetch failed. Column 'Total Events' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.
```

Comment: Maybe try internal name of the column, `Total_x0020_Events`. Space is replaced with `_x0020_` in Internal names.. Otherwise you can go to List settings -> Under columns click Total Events and check the Field name in URL. That is the internal name of the column.

Comment: dude!  I owe you 1000000 points!! thank you!! it was the _x0020_ that worked!

Comment: :) No problem.. I will add it as answer so you can accept it to close the Question.. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try internal name of the column, `Total_x0020_Events`. Space is replaced with `_x0020_` in Internal names..

Otherwise you can go to List settings -> Under columns click Total Events and check the Field name in URL. That is the internal name of the column.